# Can profile MDM settings increase FaceId's frequency to switch back to Passcode?

Tags: iphone, mdm, configuration-profiles, face-id

I have work email on my phone thanks to some MDM profile additions.

I'm finding on my iPhone XS that FaceId forces back to Passcode on every second attempt. I have added a second face - my Apple watch is not used for authentication. This frequency seems unusually high. I'm tempted to temporarily delete the MDM profile to see if this decreases the tendency of FaceId to flip back to Passcode.

My question is: **Can profile MDM settings increase FaceId's frequency to switch back to Passcode?**

Comment: What's the link with your Apple Watch?

Comment: I can disable the use of any biometric unlock method through JSS, but it is either On or Off with nothing in between.

Comment: The link with the Apple Watch was that you can set FaceId to also trigger the Apple Watch for authentication. (This was to solve a problem during heavy mask usage - when FaceId was ineffective.) I was saying I have switched this off - to make the control data isolated.

Comment: IconDaemon - perhaps you can expand that into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can profile MDM settings increase FaceId's frequency to switch back to Passcode?

Yes, you can set a timeout for when the device will require a passcode to unlock.  The default is 48 hours (172,800 seconds).  Based on your description, it appears that the Admin who deployed the policy kept the default setting.

The [MDM Restriction policy](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/restrictions-for-iphone-and-ipad-dep0f7dd3d8/1/web/1.0) is called *Enforce Face ID or Touch ID timeout*.

> I'm tempted to temporarily delete the profile to see if this decreases the tendency of FaceId to flip back to Passcode.

This will have no effect as the MDM restriction will still be in place.  The timeout value is not affected by the number of biometric (face/finger prints) assets you add to the device.

Comment: I think the OP was looking for a way to increase the amount of failed FaceID attempts before being prompted to enter the password. I don't think the OP is looking for a way to adjust the time between each time you need to enter the passcode. Are they?

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful. I was looking for a way to enter the passcode less frequently - I think both options of what you describe would help this. But before I ask the how to fix - I just wanted to know the "what" and is "is the profile even affecting this?" Which you have both answered - thankyou.

Answer (score -1):

From [Face ID, Touch ID, passcodes, and passwords](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/face-id-touch-id-passcodes-and-passwords-sec9479035f1/web):

> A passcode or password is also required if […]: There were ***five unsuccessful biometric match attempts*** (though for usability, the device might offer entering a passcode or password instead of using biometrics after a smaller number of failures).

<sup>(Emphasis and italics mine)</sup>

Normally, a password is required if 5 attempts of biometric authentication (TouchID or FaceID) are unsuccessful. But this can be set differently from an MDM system. As per the Apple Developers page [LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lapolicy/deviceownerauthenticationwithbiometrics):

> After ***two failed Face ID attempts***, the system offers a fallback option, but stops trying to authenticate with Face ID. Both Touch ID and Face ID authentication are disabled system-wide after five consecutive unsuccessful attempts, even when the attempts span multiple evaluation calls. When this happens, the system requires the user to enter the device passcode to reenable biometry.

<sup>(Emphasis and italics mine)</sup>